# Filtering out Movies by Genre- Python Movie Database

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use python's inbuilt filter() function to filter out movie titles using specified genres. Any Pointers? Another option is use an empty list and adding the filtered movies to that list but I can't get that to work either.

```
class Movie():
    def __init__(self, title, year, director, genre, language, actors, summary):
        self.title = title
        self.year = year
        self.director = director
        self.genre = genre
        self.language = language
        self.actors = actors
        self.summary = summary
        return
    def __str__(self):
        string = """
        Title: {}
        Year: {}
        Director: {}
        Genre: {}
        Language: {}
        Actors: {}
        Summary: {}""".format(self.title, self.year, self.director, self.genre, self.language, self.actors, self.summary)
        return string
# this is the filter function
def by_genre(movie_list, genre):
    movies = filter(movie_list, genre)
    return movies
#everything to this point is functioning properly    
# these are movies added to the database
Rampage = Movie('Rampage', 2018, 'Brad Peyton', 'scifi', 'English', 'The Rock', ' The Rock must rescue a endangered gorilla from poachers')
G_Galaxy = Movie('Guardians of the Galaxy', 2017, 'James Gunn', 'scifi', 'English', 'Chris Pratt', 'Chris Pratt and his ragtag group must save the universe')
Avatar = Movie('Avatar', 2009, 'James Cameron', 'scifi', 'English', 'Zoe Saldana', 'a paralyzed former Marine becomes an Avatar and falls in love, \
he is drawn into a battle for the survival of her world')
Jump = Movie('22 Jump Street', 2014, 'Phil Lord, Chris Miller', 'action', 'English', 'Channing Tatum, Jonah Hill', 'Undercover agents disguised as college students must crack a case')
Dpool2 = Movie('Deadpool 2', 2018, 'David Leitch', 'Fantasy', 'English', 'Ryan Reynolds', 'Deadpool must save a teenager from a time traveler')

#these are test codes
scifi_list = by_genre([Rampage, Avatar, Jump], 'scifi')
for m in scifi_list: print(m.title)
```

Comment: Filter takes the list and a function that returns `True` or `False`. If the return value is false, then that item is discarded from the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter function needs to have a function that returns True if an item passes a criterion. Look at the following:

```
def by_genre(movies_list, genre):
    return filter(lambda m: m.genre == genre,
                  movies_list)
```

Comment: I get an TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable.

Comment: Got the args the wrong way round. Edited

Comment: Works perfectly!  movies and movies_list should be replaced with movie_list